# Predicting Win Probabilities In-Game

Tags: machine-learning, probability, dataset

I'm looking to predict the probability of a team winning a game in basketball so that I can create something close to this: [image]

If you can't see the picture, it's a graph with time remaining on the x-axis and the probability of winning on the y-axis.

I've tried looking at similar projects online but all of them either do not show their code or only show how they created the model and none of their data. I have every possession from the 2000-01 season with the seconds remaining in the game and the score differential. I originally had it formatted so that each possession had the probability the team would win the game, before the game started, and a 0/1 representing whether or not the team had won the game. Shown by a smaller mock dataset here:[image]

I realized that doesn't make sense because each possession isn't associated with a 0/1 or the starting probability, rather the entire game is. What would be the best way to format my data so that I can obtain the probability a team will win the game after each possession?

- The definition of a possession per the NBA: A team is in possession when a player is holding, dribbling or passing the ball. Team possession ends when the defensive team gains possession or the ball hits the rim of the
  offensive team.

Comment: If a similar project explained their model, shouldn't you be able to infer what data they fed into it?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I know that similar projects used the same data that I use but none explain how they deal with have multiple observations contributing to a single output classification.

Comment: Could you explain what 'possession' means and could you also formulate your sentences in shorter bits. For instance, I don't follow the sentence *"so that each possession had the probability of the team winning before the game that the odds infer and a 0/1 representing whether or not the team had won the game."*

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sorry about that I wrote it in a bit of a hurry as I'm studying for an exam at the moment. I edited my original post to include a definition of possession, and cleaned up a sentence or two.

Answer (score 1):

Not a sports modeler here, so anyone with a better idea would be more than welcome.

It looks like you have both time-varying and non-varying predictors. You can feed both into your model by having a large design matrix with one row per second, where the non-varying predictors will simply be constant throughout a game. You will then stack the design matrix for each game on top of each other. I don't know basketball from Alpha Centauri, but my guess for reasonable predictors would be:

- a binary predictor indicating who is in possession
- a numerical predictor giving the score differential
- a numerical predictor indicating the number of seconds left
- possibly multiple predictors for characteristics or quality indicators of the players at each position, for both teams - perhaps categorical predictors giving the players' names would be enough
- a numerical predictor giving how many time outs each team has left

The target value would again be a time-constant vector, and it would be binary (for classification), or numerical (for predicting the score differential).

If you run a ML model, that should do it, those account for nonlinearities and interactions automatically. If you feed this into a classical statistical model, you might want to include transformations of time remaining (e.g., using splines), perhaps interaction terms.